# Hue (tint, color) correction using avconv

Tags: 14.04, video, ffmpeg, colors, avconv

I'm trying to make a demonstration of [orange and blue color timing](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/Orange-Blue_Contrast). I've been [told](http://forums.nesdev.com/viewtopic.php?p=151006#p151006) I can do this in the [YIQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ) domain by increasing the level of I and decreasing Q. So I want to take a video, rotate the UV plane by 33 degrees (changing hue so that YUV represent YIQ), change the planes' levels with `lutyuv`, and rotate hue back by 33 degrees.

I'm using `avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`. But it appears to lack the [hue filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-hue) and the [mp=eq2 filter](https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/adjusting-video-contrast-brightness-saturation-and-color-balance-with-ffmpeg/).

- `avplay -i some_video.webm -vf "hue=h=33"` gave "No such filter: 'hue'"
- `avplay -i some_video.webm -vf "mp=hue=100:0"` gave "No such filter: 'mp'"

What do I need to `sudo apt-get install` to rotate the UV plane of a video? Would upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 add the necessary features? Do I need to compile FFmpeg (not avconv) from source? Or would `mencoder` be preferable for this task?